# Second condition but with present tense

Tags: conditionals

> The thing with Justin, if I thought he was going to implement a ground game and **go** in there and **take** Conor McGregor down and put him against the cage and **do** what Khabib did or do what I intended to do if he was going to implement that game, I would say, ‘Justin is going to do really well against him,” Alvarez said.

What I have learnt is that we use *if + were/was + would* in second condition but this sentence has *go* instead of *went*  *take* instead of *took* and *do* instead of *did* why?

Comment: Forget about the classification of conditionals. The verbs *implement*, *go*, and *take*, are in the infinitive because the use of the auxiliary verb *going (to)* ***requires*** them to be in the infinitive. If you are asking why *going to* is used, you need to edit your question to clarify that.

Comment: You mean it's *to infinitive* where *to* works as a particle for infinitives *implement*, *go*, and *take*?

Comment: *Going to implement*, *going to go*, *going to take*, *going to do*. (For instance, you cannot use *going to took*.)

Comment: @Jason Bassford Can I say if I don't use *going to* -The thing with Justin, if I thought he implemented a ground game and went in there and took Conor McGregor down and put him against the cage and did what Khabib did or did what I intended to do if he was going to implement that game, I would say, ‘Justin is going to do really well against him,” Alvarez said.

Comment: The verb forms in the revised sentence look okay to me. (Although I have to say that the entire sentence, verb forms aside, is somewhat convoluted.)

Comment: @Jasson Brassford What do you mean by convoluted? Is the sentence not understandable?

Comment: It's quite long and difficult to easily parse on a single pass. There is also a large amount of text between the first part and the concluding part. Not to mention the fact that Alvarez speaking comes completely out of the blue at the very end (and contradicts the speaker being *I* at the start of the dialogue).